Unable to Access Mediamtx webrtc stream inside k8s cluster - Minikube
Mediamtx webrtc stream is not accessible while running inside k8s cluster in minikube
I running a mediatmx server on minikube kubernetes cluster. I am passing a rtsp stream as input to the mediamtx server through mediamtx config file as path entry.
Now I am trying to access the corresponding Webrtc stream locally from my browser, by using kubectl port forward to forward mediamtx service to localhost. But I am not able to access the webrtc stream from the browser
Steps to recreate the Issue

Create minikube cluster.
Deploy mediamtx Deployment, Service and Config Map
The Config map include custom mediamtx.yml config

Mediamtx Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: mediamtx
labels:
app: mediamtx
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
app: mediamtx
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: mediamtx
spec:
containers:

name: mediamtx
image: bluenviron/mediamtx
args: ["/mediamtx.yml"] # Explicitly specify the config file location
volumeMounts:

name: config
mountPath: /mediamtx.yml
subPath: mediamtx.yml
ports:

containerPort: 8554

containerPort: 1935

containerPort: 8888

containerPort: 8889

containerPort: 8890

containerPort: 8189
env:

name: MTX_PROTOCOLS
value: "tcp"

name: MTX_WEBRTCADDITIONALHOSTS
value: "172.19.0.1"
volumes:

name: config
configMap:
name: mediamtx-config
defaultMode: 0644  # Ensure the file is readable
Mediamtx Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: mediamtx
spec:
type: ClusterIP
ports:



name: rtsp
port: 8554
targetPort: 8554
protocol: TCP
name: rtmp
port: 1935
targetPort: 1935
protocol: TCP
name: web
port: 8888
targetPort: 8888
protocol: TCP
name: web-rtc
port: 8889
targetPort: 8889
protocol: TCP
name: rtsp-udp
port: 8890
targetPort: 8890
protocol: UDP
name: udp-extra
port: 8189
targetPort: 8189
protocol: UDP
selector:
app: mediamtx
mediamtx config map
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: mediamtx-config
data:
mediamtx.yml: |
Your custom MediaMTX configuration goes here
webrtcICEServers2:
- url: stun:stun2.1.google.com:19302
paths:
example:
mycamera:
source: rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.101.215:554/unicaststream/1
all_others:

The Config map includes custom mediamtx configuration. I have added a default rtsp stream path entry to it, And trying to access the corresponding webrtc streams.

Apply all resources, wait for medamtx pod to start. Expose mediamtx service using kubectl port-forward


Now the webrtc stream should be accessible at http://localhost:8889/mycamera, But I am not able to access it

This is pretty much identical to this other question, which has better formatting and more details.  It looks like you're merely trying to deploy prebuilt software and not programming per se; I'd recommend editing the other question if you do in fact have a programming problem.
